# Реальный и виртуальные поддомены, как разрулить

Tags: openserver

На платформе `OpenServer` имеется две версии одного сайта, мобильная и основная.

- domen.open
- m.domen.open

У домена `domen.open` имеются виртуальные поддомены на ~80 регионов (например `spb.domen.open`), то есть 80 виртуальных поддоменов, которые обрабатываются контроллером сайта на `domen.open`.

Для того чтобы локально тестировать работу полной связки мобильной и обычной версии, нет возможности дать доменам полностью разные имена.

Теперь собственно о проблеме. При попытке открыть `spb.domen.open` без каких либо хитростей мы не попадаем на нужный нам сайт. Решил этот вопрос я через настройки `OpenServer` на вкладке Алиасы, прописав алиас `*.domen.open => domen.open` и в `hosts` прописав `127.0.0.1 spb.domen.open` после чего поддомен заработал.

Но вот поддомен `m.domen.open` теперь открывает соответственно другой сайт.

Где я ошибся и как решить проблему?

> Переименовать домены нельзя!

Comment: если вы `*.domen.open` прописываете, понятно что туда и `m.domen.open` попадет, так что поведение логично.

Comment: этот комментарий не конструктивный, я понимаю что поведение логично, я как то не вижу например более логичным прописать 80 алиасов...

Comment: дак там нельзя отдельно прописать алиас `m.domen,open` что бы он проверялся до `*.domen.open` и на этом проверка завершалась? хоть тут алиас с основным именем и будут совпадать, но настроить это  в начале.

Comment: код сайтов совершенно разный, и он лежит в разных местах, проверять в контроллере другого сайта не принадлежащий домен было бы глупо, зачем 2 раза делать сложную проверку с выборкой из базы.

Comment: я вроде про алиасы писал, которые у вас в настройках OpenServer, при чем тут код контроллера?

Comment: я вообще не понял суть того что вы хотели сказать тогда.

Comment: я хотел выразить мысль, что определение домена `m.` должно в конфигурационных файлах быть раньше чем определение основного домена и его алиасов со `*`.

Comment: обратите внимание на метку вопроса...